# How to play audio through both headphones and speakers when headphones are plugged in?

Tags: audio, windows-10, speakers

I want to be able to listen to audio through both headphones and speakers when I have headphones plugged in. When I go to manage playback devices (as recommended by other SuperUser posts about this topic I've seen) only Intel SST shows up and it won't let me change the default. Also, I would like to be able to choose to only use the speakers when my headphones are plugged in as an additional option.

My current setup makes it difficult to unplug from the audio jack, so it would be nice to manage the audio on the software side.

I have a Dell XPS 13 running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes plugging the jack in half way enables you to use speakers and line out

if not then you will need external speakers and a jack splitter